# Wrong Totals Using IF and Values() in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am working on getting the amount of new sales and lost sales with regards to sales previous year and sales year to date. I am trying to show this in a table and then filtering that table with a year slicer. 
Below are the formulas that i have used:

```
SalesPY = CALCULATE(SUM(SalesData[Value]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[DateKey]))

SalesYTD = TOTALYTD(SUM(SalesData[Value]), 'Calendar'[DateKey])

NewSalesUppdate = SUMX(VALUES(SalesData[CustomerName]),IF([SalesYTD] > 0 && [SalesPY] = 0, [SalesYTD]))

LostSalesUppdate = SUMX(VALUES(SalesData[CustomerName]),IF([SalesYTD] = 0 && [SalesPY] > 0, -[SalesPY]))

LostSalesOld = IF([SalesPY] > 0 && [SalesYTD] = 0, -[SalesPY])
```

The `NewSalesUppdate` formula works as it should and sums up correctly. However `LostSalesUppdate` does not work, despite having pretty much the opposite formula compared with `NewSalesUppdate`. It seems like the `IF` statement never becomes true. That is strange because the `LostSalesOld` formula shows the right value, but it does not show the total.

All tips are appreciated!

---

**Sample Data:**

[image: Sample Data]

**Current Result:**

[image: Current Result]
*Notice how customer A had no YTD sales. The LostSalesOld shows -85000 in sales, but nothing is reflected in the total. The LostSalesUppdate shows nothing at all.*

**Desired Result:**

[image: Desired Result]
*Now one of the lost sales columns (doesn't matter which) has a value for customer A, and a total*

Comment: Can you explain with some sample (say monthly) data what you'd like to accomplish and what you're currently seeing? The SalesPY and SalesYTD measures are different (one is confined to the current date context, the other is a YTD measure). For that reason, SalesYTD would never be 0 once there has been a sale in the current year, whereas SalesPY could frequently be 0. For that reason, I wouldn't describe LostSalesUppdate and NewSalesUppdate as opposite to each other.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Leonard ! I will try to be a little more specific.

Comment: In the Table below you can see how i would like it to work. However, as i said before, the LostSalesOld formula shows -70000 for customer A in lostSales, but does not show the total. When i instead try to use LostSalesUppdated the lostSales column just becomes blank ( never becomes true). So i know that the formula works when i only use the IF statement, but it does not work when i add the Values method. Since i am filtering the SalesYTD on each customer, it feels like it should be possible for SalesYTD to be 0. 

@Leonard

Comment: I hope it is clear what i am trying to achieve. Do you have any tips on other formulas that i can use instead in order to get the desired result?

CustomerName       SalesPY         SalesYTD      NewSales     LostSales 
           A                    70000                    0                                    -70000
           B                        0                    50000           50000
Total                          70000                50000           50000           -70000

Comment: I now realize that the table that i tried to write in the comments field did not turn out that good. I would really appreciate it if you could email me at derf95stack@gmail.com, so that it would be easier for me to send images of my table in power bi. That way i think it will be easier to understand. 

If anyone else would like to help me as well, you are more than welcome to send me an email too. When we have found the answer, we can post it here, so that other people can see it. 

@Leonard

Comment: To make it easier, here is a link to one drive where i have posted the test file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtXhBVThw98Ja07SGd9hSLPNGxo 
There are a few extra measures in the file, but the ones that should be focused on are the ones that i mentioned in the first post. In the report view you may switch from year 2015 to 2016 to see how newSales/lostSales work/Dont work. If you have any tips on changes i can make in order for the lostSales to show and sum up the right values, that would be great. 
 
Best Regards

@Leonard

Comment: I've made an edit to the question to reflect the information in the PBI file from onedrive. (Comments are limited in formatting, but you can edit the question when you want to add more detail). Feel free to correct the edits if I've described what you want incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing on LostSalesUppdate, the issue is one of context. Your measure is saying "For each customer name *in the SalesData table*, show me last year's sales negated if they had sales last year and none this year".

The problem (and I'll admit it is subtle), is that **because** there are no sales for Customer A this year, Customer A is **not** in the SalesData table as far as this measure is concerned. Therefore, the rest of the formula is ignored.

What I would recommend is adding a separate table with a list of customers, similar to your date table (one row per customer). Then, update your LostSalesUppdate formula so that instead of pulling CustomerName from SalesData, it pulls it from your new customer table.

```
LostSalesUppdate =
SUMX (
VALUES ( Customer[CustomerName] ),
IF ( [SalesYTD] = 0 && [SalesPY] > 0, - [SalesPY] )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Leonard! It seems to be working as it should now.